# How to find out wifi adapter model?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking, drivers, wifi-driver

I had my wifi adapter changed a few months ago and I guess technician put other wifi adapter than original because original drivers do not work. How can I find out my wifi adapter model on windows 7 ? It's not listed in device manager..

Comment: Have you opened the back access panel? Most laptop's have either a small door or larger panel where the wireless card is visible. Are you saying no wireless adapter at all is listed in the device manager? Opening open one of these panels might revel the card is not properly connected.

Comment: If it's not listed, are there any unknown devices listed with a question mark? If not then jdh might be right and the card might not be properly connected/installed.

Answer (score 1):

For hardware to work firstly it need to be connected to some PC bus (PCI, USB), and secondly - right driver need to be loaded.

On Linux this is simple, `sudo lsusb` & `sudo lspci` are your friends.

Windows has equivalent for lsusb on it's pages, it has also its github repo:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows equivalent for lspci:

- http://mj.ucw.cz/sw/pciutils/

If you can't find your WiFi adapter either on PCI or USB, then it is not physically connected, and you need to correct this first, as appropriate driver could do nothing without hardware being plugged in.

If finding or installing Windows equivalents of lspci & lsusb is problem, you can always boot any live Linux distribution, there are plenty of them, and then run `sudo lsusb` & `sudo lspci` and print the results.

That's soft approach, some would just get screwdriver and junk adapter out and push it back in, and only after that try software approach. That could invalidate your guarantee, if PC is new and has label against user opening or tampering.

And yes, I know, sometimes users are more qualified than service workers. :)